# jQuery Mobile :: "Tap" event doesn't work on mobile, but does on desktop

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I am learning jQuery Mobile currently and I have a Tap event bound to a blank anchor tag (href is blank)

My jQuery script looks like this:

```
        <script>
    $(function(){
        $('.design-link').bind('tap', function(event){
            alert('test');
            return false;
        });
    });
    </script>
```

The alert shows when I view the page in Firefox on Mac, but on my mobile (HTC Desire running ICS) nothing happens.

Any reason why this would happen?

Cheers!

Comment: try it without the function wrapper, so just this: $('.design-link').bind('tap', function(event){
            alert('test');
            return false;
        });

Comment: No dice. A colleague tried on his iPhone as well, nothing. I know "alert()" is old skool but it should work right?

Comment: is the function in the first page that gets loaded? jQM JS for all pages needs to go in the first page loaded

Comment: The page in question is actually a seperate page. However, I added the script block to the home page as well. It still only seems to work on my computer and not my phone :(

Comment: could you add a link to the site or a http://jsfiddle.net example?

Comment: any luck? Having the same issue...